# In Chrome why does a javascript loop containing window.loction.reload(true) fail to execute?

Tags: javascript, browser, console

In Chrome's DevTools Console app I want to refresh the page a 100 time to catch an error that appears doing page load for an app I am working on. 
 The call `window.location.reload(true)` forces the page to refresh when executed from the console command line.  However, when I put it in a loop with a `wait()` function of my own devising, the refresh only executes once one everything is done, see code that follows.

I have tried using other calls in its place it works, such as printing windows.location and windows.fullscreen.  I have been looking for a browser internal call that will tell me when the refresh is complete, but haven't found that yet.

```
function wait(ms){
   var start = new Date().getTime();
   var end = start;
   while(end < start + ms) {
     end = new Date().getTime();
    console.log("tick-tock");
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i<3; i++){  
  console.log("start");
  window.location.reload(true);  //<<won't execute, but once
  wait(5000);
  console.log("stop");
};
```

I just want the browser to refresh a number of times.  I will capture the error in the logs.  I appreciate any help you can give me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `window.location.reload()` is essentially equivalent to pressing the Refresh button in your browser. When it executes, it unloads the entire page, then loads it again (with the `true` argument it also ignores the browser cache, forcing it to request the page again from the server).

Along with rendered HTML, CSS, and other assets, any JavaScript that is running (functions, loops, and variables) when a reload is initiated is discarded-- the browser starts completely from scratch with a blank environment.

The whole point to refreshing is that it resets the page and retrieves everything over again, either from the server or the cache. This will also re-fetch any JavaScript on the page (and in the console), so it wouldn't make sense to preserve data from the potentially outdated version of a page or script.

Apart from creating a Chrome extension yourself, there's likely no way to refresh a page in a loop, since all other script contexts are scoped to the current page. A hypothetical Chrome extension to do this could scan for a certain `tabId` and repeatedly refresh it based on your settings. It's possible that such a thing exists on the Chrome Web Store already, but I doubt it.

Comment: Thx IronFlare, your analysis, and description are correct.  I find it weird that the single window.location.reload() execution is held until all the javascript is done executing.  I also tested window.location.replace(location) and the same happens, as it should.  I will jump to JMeter and manipulated the browser from the outside.